# No undefined references when compiling shared library

Tags: c, shared-libraries, ld

Im wondering why Im getting no undefined references when compiling as a shared library using -shared as an option for gcc. Consider the following case:

```
#include <confuse.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cfg_opt_t opts[1];
    cfg_t *cfg = cfg_init(opts, CFGF_NOCASE);
    return 0;
}
```

libconfuse is needed here in order to run the program properly. If im compiling it as a "normal" application without specifying that libconfuse is needed (-lconfuse) im getting the following (from my perspective regular) error:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wno-unused-variable test.c -o test
/tmp/ccTVz6an.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `cfg_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If im compiling the same code as a shared library im not getting any error message regarding the library:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wno-unused-variable test.c -o test.so -shared
$ echo $?
0
```

Can someone please bring light into darkness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are compiling a (shared) library, not a program, and libraries are expected not to be complete, so undefined references do not prevent the shared library from building.

Yes, it may sound a bit surprising, particularly if you come from a OS (Windows?) where the shared libraries are always fully linked, but that's how ELF works.

If you want to ensure that all your references are are resolved when building a shared library you can use the linker option `--no-undefined`:

```
gcc -Wall -Wno-unused-variable test.c -o test.so -shared -Wl,--no-undefined
```

Note that libraries used to resolve references when linking a shared library will be added to the header of that library, as `NEEDED` entries, and then linked automatically when using that library. See `objdump -p` for details.

Answer (score 2):

With shared libraries (not static ones), you could link a library `libA.so` into your other library `libB.so`.

So you could compile your shared library as:

```
  gcc -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -fPIC test.c \
       -o libmytest.so -shared -lconfuse
```

Later you would link that library to some `main.c` with

```
  gcc -Wall main.c -lmytest -L. -o myprog
```

or you could load it at runtime, using [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) on `./libmytest.so` (read the man page about why `./` is significant to `dlopen`)

Simple explanations are in the [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/). But [Drepper's paper: *How to Write Shared Libraries*](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) is the best reference.

And it is permitted for a shared library (or even a static one) to have undefined references, since quite often the user of that library would *explicitly* link the lower level libraries needed by it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Unfortunately the answer does not fit to the question. I wanna know why im getting undefined references when not using -shared but not getting them when using -shared